# Entity Framework Exception: No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter to a known managed provider native type

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have create an SP which return Dynamic Resultsets so i have created a complex type for mapping the result sets in to entity. While executing this procedure i got the exception

**No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter to a known managed provider native type.**

Below are the function which created by  EDMX Automatically

```
 public int GetKpiComparisonResults(Nullable<global::System.Int32> p_primary_org_unit_surrogate_key, global::System.String p_org_unit_surrogate_key_csv, global::System.String p_industry_code, global::System.String p_country_code, Nullable<global::System.Boolean> p_period_type, Nullable<global::System.Int32> p_start_year, Nullable<global::System.Int32> p_end_year, Nullable<global::System.Int32> p_start_period, Nullable<global::System.Int32> p_end_period, ObjectParameter p_sql_errcode, ObjectParameter p_sql_errmsg)
        {
            //here i am declaring the parametrs
            return base.ExecuteFunction("GetKpiComparisonResults", p_primary_org_unit_surrogate_keyParameter, p_org_unit_surrogate_key_csvParameter, p_industry_codeParameter, p_country_codeParameter, p_period_typeParameter, p_start_yearParameter, p_end_yearParameter, p_start_periodParameter, p_end_periodParameter, p_sql_errcode, p_sql_errmsg);


        }
```

I need the results to a complex type. So i have changed the method like below

```
   public ObjectResult<KpiComparisonResult> GetKpiComparisonResults(Nullable<global::System.Int32> p_primary_org_unit_surrogate_key, global::System.String p_org_unit_surrogate_key_csv, global::System.String p_industry_code, global::System.String p_country_code, Nullable<global::System.Boolean> p_period_type, Nullable<global::System.Int32> p_start_year, Nullable<global::System.Int32> p_end_year, Nullable<global::System.Int32> p_start_period, Nullable<global::System.Int32> p_end_period, ObjectParameter p_sql_errcode, ObjectParameter p_sql_errmsg)
        {
            //here i am declaring the parametrs
            return base.ExecuteStoreQuery<KpiComparisonResult>("GetKpiComparisonResults", p_primary_org_unit_surrogate_keyParameter, p_org_unit_surrogate_key_csvParameter, p_industry_codeParameter, p_country_codeParameter, p_period_typeParameter, p_start_yearParameter, p_end_yearParameter, p_start_periodParameter, p_end_periodParameter, p_sql_errcode, p_sql_errmsg);


        }
```

when executing this method i got exception? How can i manage dynamic resultsets in EntityFramework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4.1 Raw SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405010/entity-framework-4-1-raw-sql)

Comment: i think it's a generic exception. How can i manage dynamic resultsets?